# "Create Nonclustered Index", What is that and how do I make one?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am new to SQL and am writing a query where I return a lot of information from multiple tables for a purchase order.

My query was running slow so I googled around and many advised to look into the execution plan. So I did that but I don't fully understand the results.

My execution plan says,

> "Missing Index (Impact 99.8849): CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [] ON [dbo].[Container] ([TrackingNumber])
>   INCLUDE ([ResolvedCarrierTrackingLink])

The table it is talking about, `[dbo].[Container]`, adding that made my query go from taking `2 seconds` to taking `7 seconds`. So obviously, it is right and there is some sort of problem with this table.

How do I create this index? Is this something I can do in my query or do I have to go into the actual table and mess around there? Is this a temporary change for the specific query I'm running or is this a permanent change? Is there a good resource guide for understanding the results of the the execution plan and  what they mean?

This is my full query code:

```
SELECT
    o.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number as Shopify_Num,
    o.Control_Number, 
    o.Date_Entered as AMT_Timestamp,
    CASE 
       WHEN p.PickTicket_Number IS NULL
          THEN ist.Stage_Code 
          ELSE pst.Stage_Code 
    END AMT_Stage,
    CASE 
       WHEN p.PickTicket_Number IS NULL
          THEN i.PickTicket_Number 
          ELSE p.PickTicket_Number 
    END PickTicket_Number,
    i.Invoice_Number,
    CASE 
       WHEN o.Order_Status = 30 THEN 'CANCELED' 
       WHEN o.Order_Status = 45 THEN 'SHIPPED' 
       WHEN o.Order_Status = 10 THEN 'NORMAL' 
       WHEN o.Order_Status = 20 THEN 'NORMAL' 
    END Order_Status, 
    od.Odet_Line_Number,
    od.Item_Number,
    st.Description,
    od.Color_Code,
    c.Color_Description,
    o.Order_Value AS Total_Price_Before_Discount, 
    od.Price * od.Quantity_Ordered AS Line_Price_Before_Discount, 
    od.Discount_Value, 
    od.Discount_Percentage, 
    od.Price * od.Quantity_Ordered-od.Discount_Value AS Line_Price_After_Discount,
    SUM(od.Price * od.Quantity_Ordered - od.Discount_Value) OVER (PARTITION BY o.control_number) AS Total_Price_After_Discount,
    od.Tax_Value, od.Tax_Percentage,
    od.Quantity_Ordered,
    od.Quantity_Allocated,
    od.Quantity_Invoiced,
    CASE 
       WHEN od.Line_Status = 90 THEN 'ALLOCATED'
       WHEN od.Line_Status = 80 THEN 'CANCELED' 
       WHEN od.Line_Status = 70 THEN 'SHIPPED' 
       WHEN od.Line_Status = 50 THEN 'NORMAL' 
    END Line_Status,
    CASE  
       WHEN sh.packslip IS NOT NULL
          THEN 'SHIPPED & UPLOADED' 
          ELSE z.status 
    END Accellos_Status,
    CASE 
       WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL
          THEN ph.Date_modfy 
          ELSE sh.Date_modfy 
    END Accellos_Timestamp,  
    o.Warehouse_Code,
    b.UPS_Tracking_Number Tracking_Number, 
    CASE 
       WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL 
          THEN ph.ship_name 
          ELSE sh.SHIP_NAME 
    END Customer_Name,
    CASE 
       WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL 
          THEN ph.SHIP_ADD1 
          ELSE sh.SHIP_ADD1 
    END Customer_Addr, 
    CASE 
       WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL 
          THEN ph.SHIP_ADD2 
          ELSE sh.SHIP_ADD2 
    END Customer_Addr2, 
    CASE 
       WHEN sh.packslip IS NULL 
          THEN ph.SHIP_CITY 
          ELSE sh.SHIP_CITY 
    END Customer_City, 
    case when sh.packslip is null then ph.SHIP_PROV else sh.SHIP_PROV end Customer_State, 
    case when sh.packslip is null then ph.SHIP_ZIP else sh.SHIP_ZIP end Customer_Zip,  

    o.Ship_Via_Code,
    case when sh.packslip is null then ph.SHIP_VIA else sh.SHIP_VIA end Ship_Via,   
    sv.Description_1 as Ship_Descrp,
    case when sh.packslip is null then ph.SHIP_SERVC else sh.SHIP_SERVC end Ship_Service,  
    case when sh.packslip is null then ph.SERVICE else sh.SERVICE end Service_Descrp,  
    case when sh.packslip is null then ph.SHIP_NUM else sh.SHIP_NUM end Ship_Num,  
    case when sh.packslip is null then ph.COST_SHIP else sh.COST_SHIP end Ship_Cost,
    SUM(od.Freight_Charges) OVER(PARTITION BY o.control_number) AS Shipping_Cost_To_Customer,  
    case when sh.packslip is null then ph.SHIP_WGHT else sh.SHIP_WGHT end Ship_Weight,
    cont.ResolvedCarrierTrackingLink
FROM
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Orders o (nolock)
JOIN
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Order_Detail od (nolock) ON o.Company_Code = od.Company_Code 
                                                           AND o.Division_Code = od.Division_Code 
                                                           AND o.Control_Number  = od.Control_Number
LEFT JOIN
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].PickTickets P (nolock) ON o.Company_Code = p.Company_Code 
                                                         AND o.Division_Code = p.Division_Code 
                                                         AND o.Control_Number = p.Control_Number
LEFT JOIN
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices i (nolock) ON o.Company_Code = i.Company_Code 
                                                      AND o.Division_Code = i.Division_Code 
                                                      AND o.Control_Number = i.Control_Number
LEFT JOIN
   [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].box b (nolock) ON o.Company_Code = b.Company_Code 
                                                AND o.Division_Code = b.Division_Code 
                                                AND i.PickTicket_Number = b.PickTicket_Number
LEFT JOIN
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Invoices_Stage ist (nolock) ON o.Company_Code = ist.Company_Code  
                                                AND o.Division_Code = ist.Division_Code 
                                                AND i.Invoice_Number = ist.Invoice_Number
LEFT JOIN 
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].PickTickets_Stage pst (nolock) on o.Company_Code=pst.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=pst.Division_Code and p.PickTicket_Number=pst.PickTicket_Number
LEFT JOIN
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Color c (nolock) on od.Color_Code = c.Color_Code
LEFT JOIN
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Style st (nolock) on o.Company_Code=st.Company_Code and o.Division_Code=st.Division_Code and od.item_number=st.item_number and c.color_code = st.color_code 
LEFT JOIN 
    [JMNYC-AMTDB].[AMTPLUS].[dbo].Ship_Via_File sv (nolock) on o.ship_via_code = sv.ship_via_code
LEFT JOIN
    pickhead ph (nolock) ON p.PickTicket_Number = ph.packslip
LEFT JOIN
    Z_Status z ON ph.PROCSTEP = z.procstep
LEFT JOIN 
    SHIPHIST sh (nolock) ON o.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = sh.cust_po
LEFT JOIN
    [A1Ship].[dbo].Container cont ON cont.TrackingNumber = b.UPS_Tracking_Number
WHERE 
    CONCAT((o.Company_Code), (o.Division_Code)) = '03001' 
    AND o.Customer_Number = 'ecom2x'
    AND o.Customer_Purchase_Order_Number = '3124188'
```

Comment: `concat((o.Company_Code),(o.Division_Code))='03001'` is unlikely to be good for your performance either I'm afraid. Also, wwhy do you have `(nolock)` everywhere?  Firstly, using a table hint without `WITH` is deprecated, however, if you're new to SQL I doubt you know of the real ramifications of using it either. `NOLOCK` doesn't actually mean "Read this table without locking it".

Comment: [Bad Habits: Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://blogs.sentryone.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/)

Comment: You need to [give us the execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) for anyone to be able to help you. Also, you stated that it sped up your query, which means you already created the index (and you posted how), so what don't you know how to do? Creating an index is not temporary, unless you then drop it, which doesn't make much sense. Currently you are asking a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You want to know about indexes because you think that's the culprit. What you really want is for your query to be faster, which could or could not have to do with a missing index.

Comment: Hint:  `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [] ON [dbo].[Container] ([TrackingNumber]) INCLUDE ([ResolvedCarrierTrackingLink])`.

Comment: @Larnu I have nolock everywhere because my supervisor told me to put it there, he said it is because the database I am accessing is live and has orders constantly being added so we don't want to lock the database and have an order not be properly added. As for the concat issue, would something like

where o.Company_Code = '03' and o.Division_Code='001'  be better?

Comment: @scsimon Here it is, https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=HyBu33oZV

Comment: @GordonLinoff Do I just have to add that one line, and it will create the index for me? Where do I add it? Before all the select statements?

Comment: @Natan if your database is live, and constantly having updates, then using `NOLOCK` sounds like an awful idea; unless of course you're happy with the data being wrong (a lot). I would be seriously questioning my supervisor if they told me to do that, Either way though, like I said, `NOLOCK` doesn't not cause locks, so that information they have provided you with is just plain wrong.

Comment: @Larnu Is there a keyword I should replace it with if I do not want my queries to affect the live data entering the database, or should I just remove all the nolocks?

Comment: If your boss told you to use nolock i wouldn't go creating indexes on the fly.

Comment: I would personally suggest a different topic if you want to considering replacing with `NOLOCK`. The question here is about the poor performance. @scsimon, however, raises a very valuable point that if your supervisor has made the recommendation of using `NOLOCK`, then just adding an index on the fly is going to be a good thing. There are likely far more fundamental problems here, however, I would suggest looking at some of the links in the article I posted, such as https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/

Comment: We aren't trying to be rude, just being cautions. When you ask what an NCI is, then the next step shouldn't be to create one. By all means go ahead if your boss is cool with that, but it's like taking medicine but not knowing all the side affects and other things that you will have to do to not make things worse. @GordonLinoff gave you the command.

Answer (score 0):

> What is that?

You really should do some research on indexes, but basically they tend to make certain queries faster while slowing down updates, inserts and deletes.

> How to make one?

At least in the latest version of SSMS, you can right click the message and choose Missing Index Details which will open a script editor window.  You can edit the name of the index.  For example, the index you posted would look something like this:

```
 CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Container_TrackingNumber_INC_ResolvedCarrierTrackingLink] 
   ON [dbo].[Container] ([TrackingNumber]) 
   INCLUDE ([ResolvedCarrierTrackingLink])
```

You can execute this tsql code to create the index.  Depending on your organization you may need permissions added to your login/user to execute this and also may need approval from an OPS or DBA team.